# XML as ouput of stored procedure over different servers using linked servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have a stored procedure in a server and I'm trying to access that stored procedure from another server using a linked server.

Now, the stored procedure has an XML output parameter. The stored procedure returns a dataset, a varchar output parameter, and an XML output parameter.

Is there a way to get the XML data from another server?

Server 1:

```
DECLARE para4 XML 
EXEC sp_name para1, para2 ,para3, para4 output
```

server 2:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_name 
BEGIN 
    SET para4 = (SELECT ... FROM #table_name 
                 FOR XML PATH('RowData'),TYPE, ROOT('Output') ) 

    SELECT * FROM #tablename 
END
```

Comment: If you've set up the linked server, then just call the procedure. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is with the XML output parameter. I'm not able to get XML data over servers.

Comment: Why not? Elaborate on your problem. Are you getting an error? What is the SQL you are using to get said error?

Comment: I'm getting below error:
Msg 9512, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Xml data type is not supported as a parameter to remote calls.

Comment: server 1:
declare para4 XML
exec sp_name para1, para2 ,para3, para4 output

server 2:
create proc sp_name
BEGIN

Set para4= (
   select ...  from #table_name 
   FOR XML PATH('RowData'),TYPE, ROOT('Output')
   )

  select * from #tablename
END

Comment: @MitchWheat That question relates to selecting directly from a table. None of the answers show how to pass it back from a stored procedure

Comment: I would say create another stored procedure on the remote server that converts the `output` parameter to `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: re-opened........

Comment: I *really* hope that your procedure isn't *really* called `sp_name`.

Comment: @Larnu, no its not

Comment: I'm thinking of inserting the returned dataset of the sp to a temp table and convert the temp table to XML format. Not sure will work or not.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to send a whole batch to the other server that runs the proc and martials the result.  Something like

```
create or alter proc sp_name @para4 xml out
as
BEGIN 
  Set @para4= ( select * from sys.objects FOR XML PATH('RowData'),TYPE, ROOT('Output') ) 
  select 1 a, 'hello' b
END
```

Then from the other server

```
exec('

declare @doc xml
create table #t(a int, b varchar(20))

insert into #t(a,b)
exec SomeDb..sp_name @para4 = @doc out

select cast(@doc as nvarchar(max)) doc, * 
from #t

') at LinkedServer
```